# momentum conservation and gluons

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, virtual-particles

The process is the following:
$$e^-e^+ \rightarrow photon \rightarrow quark + antiquark$$

Regarding the momentum conservation law, how come we have a photon of spin 1 and at the end some meson with spin 0? 
Are gluons "behind this"? If this is correct, at which point are they radiated? From quarks? Or? Is this photon a virtual photon or not? I'm a bit confused here.

Answer (score 5):

Ignore the gluon for the moment

[image: e-e+to qqb]

> Regarding the momentum conservation law, how come we have a photon of spin 1 and at the end some meson with spin 0?

First of all spins are angular momentum  not momentum. Secondly the two quarks have a spin 1/2 which will add to  either 0 or 1, and 1 conserves the angular momentum at the vertex.

All intermediate lines in Feynman diagrams describe a virtual particle, in this case the line describes a particle with the quantum numbers of a photon, but not the mass. It is off mass shell and by definition virtual.

> Are gluons "behind this"?

No. Quarks couple to electromagnetic fields because they are charged. The vertex is electromagnetic. Quarks couple to gluons because they have [color charge.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_charge), and actually no free quarks exist because the attraction created by the virtual gluons ties quarks up into mesons and baryons; this can happen at a later stage as the green gluon shows here, which should end up to another quark antiquark line to make maybe a rho-meson (spin one, used to be called vector meson dominance).